# How to `git add path/to/submodule` but with a specific submodule hash?

Tags: git, repository, commit, git-submodules, gradle-submodule

How to perform `git add path/to/submodule` but in a way that will update the staging area to have the submodule set to a specific submodule hash instead of the currently checked out hash?

This would be very useful for me when splitting a bulk of changes into separate PRs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to checkout that commit in the submodule and then commit it in the superproject:

```bash
cd path/to/submodule
git checkout $COMMIT_HASH
cd ../back/to/superproject
git add path/to/submodule
git commit -m "Update submodule"
```